# Debugging a switch statement in a C-based programming puzzle

Tags: c, puzzle

I came across this puzzle [here](http://www.gowrikumar.com/c/index.html). I can't figure out why **NONE** is not printed. Any ideas?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
      int a=10;
      switch(a)
      {
              case '1':
                  printf("ONE\n");
                  break;
              case '2':
                  printf("TWO\n");
                  break;
              defa1ut:
                  printf("NONE\n");
      }
      return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you have a typo in the `default` label?

Comment: I meant to say: +1 for a self contained question with the external link.

Comment: Syntax coloring at SO gives it away right away. `defa1ut` is not blue. Also, `defau1t` would've worked better. Or even `defauIt`, as the code font is typically Sans Serif, and in those, uppercase i and lowercase L are indistinguishable.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`defa1ut:` is a syntactically valid label, e.g. for a `goto` but not the  `default` of the switch statement.

If you compile with gcc with enough warnings it will point this out:

> ajw@rapunzel:/tmp > gcc -Wall -Wextra test.c
>   test.c: In function ‘main’: test.c:13:15: warning: label ‘defa1ut’
>   defined but not used

It's a good argument for building with warnings cranked up high and aiming for 0 warnings in every build.

Comment: @Henning - no it's not, it's written `defa1ut`. Hmm looks like someone edited the puzzle out of this puzzle temporarily.

Comment: @awoodland: It wasn't when I looked at the question -- somebody had "helpfully" edited the question to correct it to `default`. :-(

Comment: it would have been more subtle if they'd still spelled default correctly.

Comment: @tipycalFlow - yes, it set off my "bad spelling" alarm well before the "what's that 1 doing there?" alarm went off.

Answer (score 3):

If `defa1ut` is a typo for `default` and the string "NONE" is printed:

This is because `'1'` and `1` is different.

`'1'` means the ASCII value of the character `'1'` whose value in decimal is `49`.  and  `1` is an integer.

The first case will be true if the value of `a` is `49` or `'1'` , but as `a=10` so it is neither equal to `'1'` nor equals to `'2'` and thus `default` is executed (if it existed, and `defa1ut` is not a typo).

If `defa1ut` is not a typo for `default` and simply nothing is printed:

In this case you have no `default` instead which look like it is `defa1ut` which will act as a normal label, so simply nothing will be printed.

Answer (score 1):

default is spelled wrong. and so that case is never reached.
http://codepad.org/gQPA6p4s

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
      int a=10;
      switch(a)
      {
              case '1':
                  printf("ONE\n");
                  break;
              case '2':
                  printf("TWO\n");
                  break;
              defalut:
                  printf("NONE\n");
              mickey_mouse:
                  printf("No Mickey\n");
              default :
                  printf("CORRECT DEFAULT\n");
      }
      return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since defa1ut is not keyword, it should be addressed with a `case` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think it should be printed?

`defa1ut` is different from `default`