# C 'switch' usage?

Tags: c++, c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Debugging a switch statement in a C-based programming puzzle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7175348/need-help-solving-a-c-based-programming-puzzle)

I found the below C question on web:

```
  #include<stdio.h>
  int main()
  {
          int a=10;
          switch(a)
          {
                  case '1':
                      printf("ONE\n");
                      break;
                  case '2':
                      printf("TWO\n");
                      break;
                  defa1ut:
                      printf("NONE\n");
          }
          return 0;
  }
```

Although I never used 'switch' of int '10' with char '1', I assume the worst would be a non-compile, or 'default' get executed. But no, on my VStudio, it goes directly to 'return 0'. Why is this?

By the way, although I had a few years of experience in C programming, my previous motto was to stick to MSDN or available code samples. Now with the interviews and questions, the solidness of my skill is definitely being challenged.

Comment: `defa1ut` should be `default`

Comment: Is defa1ut a typo error or in the code also it is like this?

Comment: But he is also asking about comparing ints and chars, so it isn't exactly the same question.

Comment: I don't see any C++ features, but I do see stdio.h being included. C++ tag should be removed.

Comment: I don't think it's a matter of skill. Perhaps you need your glasses prescription updated? Because it's hard to imagine that "defa1ut" doesn't leap out at one. I could understand "defau1t", which might look reasonable in some fonts.

Comment: @JimBalter:  It didn't leap out at me, and I'm near-sighted.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`defa1ut` is not the same as `default`.

That's an unused and unreachable label.

Comment: Turning warnings up would have made this obvious.  Most compilers will emit a "no default" warning if there's no `default` in a `switch`.

Comment: @JohnDibling: Not to mention `unused label` and `unreachable code`.

Answer (score 4):

As SLaks pointed out, `defa1ut` is a user defined label (e.g. for a `goto`), not the switch keyword `default`. This is why you aren't seeing the expected output.

But to answer your other question, in C you can compare `char` literals with integers. In this case `'1'` has a numerical value of 49, assuming you are using the ASCII character set.

Assuming you meant `default`, and you are using ASCII, your code sample is equivalent to this:

```
      int a=10;
      switch(a)
      {
              case 49:             // ASCII value of '1'
                  printf("ONE\n");
                  break;
              case 50:             // ASCII value of '2'
                  printf("TWO\n");
                  break;
              default:
                  printf("NONE\n");
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are reading `defa1ut` as `default`; default is C language's keyword but `defau1t` is not. If you want the output to be simply "NONE" use `default` instead of `defau1t`.